# Parenting Armature to Mesh using Automatic Weights rotates Mesh

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature

I'm very new to blender and 3D rendering in general, so I'm not really sure what I'm doing. I've been following various YouTube tutorials to learn but none have addressed this problem. It's probably an easy fix, which is why I can't find a video about it, but I can't seem to figure it out. When I try to parent the rig with automatic weights, the mesh rotates. Here's what I mean.

[image: Before automatic weights]

This is what it looks like before automatic weights.

[image: After automatic weights]

This is what it looks like after I apply automatic weights. Thank you to anyone who helps! Here's my blender file if you need it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the file you've provided, your mesh objects are parented to an object "Armature" which has unapplied rotation which those mesh objects inherit.  When you parent these objects to a different armature like "rig", those objects are first being unparented *without* keep transforms, then re-parented to rig.

Solution: select all mesh objects, alt-p unparent with keep transforms, parent to "rig" with automatic weights.  (Optional, recommended: before parenting to rig, apply all transforms on all mesh objects.)

Note that this isn't the only problem here; automatic weights are not going to work well on this mesh anyways, and alternate methods of weighting (like painting) is recommended instead.  Just answering the specific issue you're asking about, the 90 degree rotation on parenting.

Comment: Shirlock Holmes strikes again!

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll look into painting :)